# Marketing Cloud emails to Salesforce reports?

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforce-id, marketing-cloud-connect

To send to Salesforce reports, we need to have the Contact ID and Email address present. However does the Contact ID need to be the 18-digit version?

Does Marketing Cloud also check if the recipients exist on AllSubscribers list and only send to those who do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you select the report within marketing cloud the id passed by Sales/Service Cloud should suffice (if the same value is passed as is displayed and exported when using reports, this will be the 15-digit version). The only difference between the 15 and 18-digit ids is case sensitivity. If you need further information on that matter and like to see how conversion works (including code in different languages), you can check out my [sf15to18 github repository](https://github.com/mslabina/sf15to18).

The contacts don't need to be on All Subscribers, as the contacts are added automatically. Only explicitly unsubscribed contacts won't receive the email.

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much! So in the end I can use either, the 15 or 18 digit ID?

Comment: As far as I know you can, but ids in reports always are the 15-digit version at least for all reports I've seen.